# Magento2: How to validate a specific system-configuration field on the server-side before save?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, system-config

I have a custom module with some system configuration fields that needs to be validated on the server side (API credentials, etc...).
At the moment, I'm using an observer on the `admin_system_config_changed_section_{my_module}` event, but I'm looking for a way to validate an API-Key field before it's saved (& then throw errors if needed).
*The validation process *must* be on the server side. I'm not looking for a validation class that uses JS.
-- Any idea?

Comment: https://alanstorm.com/magento_system_config_validation/

Comment: this will help you

Comment: It's for M1 while I'm on M2 + I need a *server-side* validation.

Answer (score 0):

To validate system configuration field you need to add validate tag like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="webkul" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Webkul</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="test" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Test Configuration</label>
            <tab>webkul</tab>
            <resource>Webkul_Test::config_test</resource>
            <group id="settings" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="custom_email" translate="label comment" sortOrder="0" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enter Email Id</label>
                    <validate>validate-email</validate><!-- here you can mention as your need -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

find default magento validation class here
http://blog.i13websolution.com/magento-2-validation-rules/

Comment: Will it do the validation on *server-side* as I mentioned? (I think not)

Comment: use `backend_model`